# SSO with ADFS 2.0 Missing NameId

Tags: single-sign-on

I am setting up SSO with ADFS 2.0. Using the same instruction as the following link.  http://blog.rhysgoodwin.com/cloud/salesforce-sso-with-adfs-2-0-everything-you-need-to-know/

On the server I have set:

LDAP Attribute: User Principal Name
Outgoing Claim Type: Name ID

The problem is that the SAML response from the server is missing the NameId attribute.  I have tried changing the Outgoing Claim Type to email but no luck.  Please help because i been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: i too very eager to see any solution that would be offered by any experts for your question. i am also having your task in my plate to implement...

Comment: Anyone can help me out?  I talked to SFDC tech but they cannot figure it out.  Waiting for the MS tech to look and see if there's something wrong with AD.

Answer (score 1):

I had then same issue and I fix it by install Windows6.1-KB2681584-v3-x64.msu and in Edit Rule in ADFS  I had this mapping LDAP:
E-Mail-Addresses to Name ID (the space caracter between Name and ID is important)

Regards